# Convergence in $L^1$ of ratio of random variables with denominator positive but not bounded away from zero?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, statistics, convergence-divergence

Let $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}, \{Y_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be such that $X_n$ converges to a constant $a$ in L1 (and hence in probability); $Y_n\geq c > 0$ for all $n$, and $Y_n$ converges in probability to a constant $b\geq 1$.  In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2730010/convergence-in-l1-of-ratio-of-random-variables) it was proved that $E[\frac{X_n}{Y_n}]\rightarrow a/b$. Just to note, I am interested in continuous random variables, if that makes any difference.

I am wondering can the condition that $Y_n \ge c > 0$ for all $n$ be weakened to $Y_n > 0$ for all $n$? In particular because in practise $Y_n$ could be the sample variance which is a positive random variable but not generally bounded away from $0$.

Intuitively it seems like if the density of $Y_n$ decays fast enough at the origin for all $n$ we might still be able to say $E[\frac{X_n}{Y_n}] \to a/b$ even if there is no $c >0$ such that $Y_n \ge c$ for all $n$?

Comment: There is already a counterexample in the thread you linked: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2730526/171159

Comment: See my comment on the post below, I am aware we can't weaken it in general, I am wondering whether we can weaken it in specific situations. Such as when $Y_n$ is the sample variance.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, in general, remove the intermediate $c$ such that $Y_n \geq c > 0$. Imagine taking, independent of $X_n$, $Y_n = 1$ with probability $1-1/n$ and $Y_n = 1/n^2$ with probability $1/n$. We have $Y_n \to 1$ in probability since $P(|Y_n - 1| \neq 0) = 1/n$.
However, $$E[X_n/Y_n] = E[X_n] E[1/Y_n] = E[X_n](n^2\cdot \frac1n + 1\cdot(1-\frac1n)) \to a \cdot \infty = \infty$$ if $a \neq 0$.

Recall Vitali's convergence theorem that tells us that $L^1$ convergence is equivalent to uniform integrability + convergence in probability. The $Y_n \geq c > 0$ condition guarantees both UI and convergence in probability, but $Y_n > 0$ does not.

Comment: I am aware we can't remove it in general, what I am interested in is what conditions on $Y$ will allow us to remove it. I mentioned the sample variance as an example since that arises alot in the denominator in applications, and the sample variance behaves much nicer as $n$ increases than the example you showed. So my intuition is that when $Y_n$ is the sample variance for $n$ observations of a random variable $Y$, if the distribution of the sample variance decays rapidly as it approaches zero, maybe we can weaken it. Do you think this is possible?

Comment: I don't think being a sample variance would help. If the distribution from which you are sampling has a lot of mass near a point, the same problem will occur.

Comment: Yeah, exactly. In other words, I concur. (just trying to attain the minimum character limit which was satisfied before I typed "other")

Comment: @nullUser But it still seems like it should depend on how fast the decay is near zero. I should clarify that when I say how fast the decay is near zero, I mean the decay of the probability mass/density function of $Y_n$.

Comment: If $Y_n  = 1$ with probability $1- 1/n^3$ and $Y_n =1/n^2$ with probability $1/n^3$ then $E[X_n/Y_n] \to a$.

Comment: In the case of normally distributed iid observations, for example, the sample variance is a scaled chi-squared distribution which is not bounded away from zero but its density decays fast at the origin. The mean of its [inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-chi-squared_distribution) is finite.

Comment: @MattAPelto and nullUser: In light of this information do you agree that there are circumstances when it can be weakened? If so, what is the precise condition needed on the decay of the density of a continuous random variable $Y_n$ near the origin so that $E[X_n/Y_n] \to a/b$?

Comment: @csss Yes, the condition can certainly be weakened, the $Y_n \geq c > 0$ is a sufficient condition, not necessary, as you pointed out. As I mentioned, the condition you are looking for is $X_n/Y_n \to a/b$ in probability and $X_n/Y_n$ is uniformly integrable. Any "simpler" condition is likely to be a sufficient one, but not necessary as well.