# Expectation of $\frac{X_1 Y_1 + X_2 Y_2 + ... + X_n Y_n}{X_1 + X_2 + ... + X_n}$ where $Y_1, Y_2, ... Y_n$ are I.I.D. and $X_i = g(Y_i)$

Tags: probability, expected-value

I'm not sure how to start as expanding it into integrals makes it very messy. I have a feeling that the expectation for $n = 1$ is the same for $n = 100$ and so the expectation is just $E[Y_1]$. Is this true? How can I show this?

Comment: This is not an answer, that's why I am posting it as a comment. You have $\mathbb{E}[\dfrac{X_1Y_1}{X_1}]=\mathbb{E}[\dfrac{nX_1Y_1}{nX_1}]$. Since all the $Y_i$ come from the same distribution, then last term is equivalent to the term you want to show. Clearly, this is not super rigorous. Looking forward to a more rigorous answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concretely what you can say is: Assuming $E(Y_i|X_i) = E(Y_j|X_j) $:
$$E\left(\frac{\sum_i X_i Y_i}{\sum_i X_i}\right) = E_{X_{1:N}}E_{Y_{1:N}}\left(\frac{\sum_i X_i Y_i}{\sum_i X_i}\  | \ X_{1:N}\right)= E_{X_{1:N}}\left(\frac{\sum_i X_i E(Y_i|X)}{\sum_i X_i}\right)  $$ $$= E_{X_{1:N}}\left(\frac{\sum_i X_i E(Y_i|X_i)}{\sum_i X_i}\right) = E_{X_{1:N}}\left( E(Y_j|X_j) \frac{\sum_i X_i}{\sum_i X_i}\right) = E_{X_{1:N}}(E(Y_j|X_j)) = E(Y_j)$$
for any $j$

The condition $E(Y_i|X_i) = E(Y_j|X_j)$ could hold in some cases even if $X = g(Y)$.

For example when $Y$ follows $U[-2,2]$ and

$X = 1$ when $-1 \leq Y \leq 1$ and $X = 0$ otherwise.

In this case $E(Y|X = 0) = E(Y | X = 1) = 0$

As $n \rightarrow \infty$:

By Strong Law of large numbers,

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem gives:
$$\frac{\sum_i X_i Y_i}{\sum_i X_i} \rightarrow \ distribution \rightarrow \frac{E(XY)}{E(X)}$$

For $L_1$ convergence assuming $B \leq |X_i|,|Y_i| \leq C$ for $B>0$ i.e.,

$$E\left(\frac{\sum_i X_i Y_i}{\sum_i X_i}\right) \rightarrow \frac{E(XY)}{E(X)}$$

see:[Convergence in $L^1$ of ratio of random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2730010/convergence-in-l1-of-ratio-of-random-variables)

Comment: Strange answer. Take $g(y)=y$ and let $n$ go to $+\infty.$ : you land on $$\frac{E(Y^2)}{E(Y)}\neq E(Y).$$

Comment: Hi @GérardLetac i assumed $E(Y_i|X_i) = E(Y_j|X_j) $. I made this assumption clear now. Thanks for the catch

Comment: Oh, I missed the ''assuming" If $g$ is one to one it implies $Y_i=Y_j$  where $Y_i$ and $Y_j$ are independent $\Rightarrow$ $Y_i$ is constant almost surely. In this case $E(Y^2)=E(Y)^2$ is correct.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I don't understand the assumption fully (why do we need it?). We know that $Y_i$ are IID and thus wouldn't that mean $Y_i/g(Y_i)$ are also IID? Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Here $Z_i \rightarrow E(XY)$ and $g(Z_i) \rightarrow E(X)$ and hence $Z_i/g(Z_i) \rightarrow E(XY)/E(Z)$. For this see the link at the end of my answer. No need of $Z_i/g(Z_i)$ to be iid for this to hold. Law of large numbers is needed to prove $Z_i,g(Z_i)$ individually converges to the expectations. For convergence of $Z_i$ we use the fact $\sum X_iY_i/n$ are sum of iid and for convergence of $g(Z_i)$ we use the fact that the $\sum X_i/n$ are sum of iid.

Comment: How can the assumption $E(Y_i\mid X_i)=E(Y_j\mid X_j)$ make sense? I didn’t read the rest of your answer so perhaps this is a typo?

Comment: @AndrewZhang OP asked for convergence to $E(Y)$ and this is the case where i could find it hold. I dont think this forces $X_i,Y_i$ to be independent. i have also included convergence results in general.

Comment: @AndrewZhang the condition $E(Y_i|X_i) = E(Y_j | X_j)$ implies $X_i,Y_i$ are uncorrelated. Not sure if converse is true. But its not clear whether this condition implies independence of $X_i,Y_i$.

Comment: @AndrewZhang i have added an example where this assumption will hold in my answer above. Read the full answer.

Comment: @Balajisb Sorry I don't know what is $L_1$. Is it important?

Comment: $L^1$ convergence of $Z_i$ to $Z$ means $E(|Z_i-Z|) \rightarrow 0$ which is stronger than $E(Z_i) \rightarrow E(Z)$

Comment: Just to confirm, in my case $Z_i = \frac{1}{n} \sum X_i Y_i$ does exhibit $L_1$ convergence, correct?

Comment: $Z_n = 1/n \sum X_i Y_i$ exhibit convergence in probability to $E(XY)$ and $M_n = 1/n \sum X_i$ exhibit convergence in probability to $E(X)$ and together with assumption $B \leq |X_i|,|Y_i| \leq C$ for $B>0$ this implies $L_1$ convergence of $Z_n/M_n$ to $E(Z_n)/E(M_n)$. Is it clear ?

Comment: I see, thanks! One more question, how do you interpret $E(Y_i | X_i)$ if $X_i$ is continuous? Do you have an easy example I can look up? Thanks again!

Comment: Consider the same $Y$ uniform between $[-2,2]$ with $X = |Y|$, Here also $E(Y|X) = 0$ independent of $X$. $E(Y|X) = \int y f(y|x) dx $ where $f(y|x) = f(y,x)/f(x)$ where $f(.)$ is the pdf

Comment: Note that $f(y)$ and $f(x)$ are continuous pdf in my example, $X=|Y|$, but $f(y,x)$ is a discrete pmf. I can explain more if you want. but put up a separate question and ping me the link here. i will explain..too much to type in comments... but if all OK then great. Cheers !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146489/discussion-between-b2vsi-and-balaji-sb).

Answer (score 0):

If $g>0$, $L(s)=E(e^{-sX_1})$ and $L_1(s)=E(X_1Y_1e^{-sX_1})$ then
$$E\frac{X_1Y_1+\cdots+X_nY_n}{X_1+\cdots+X_n}=n\int_0^{\infty}L_1(s)L^{n-1}(s)ds.$$

Comment: Can u post the derivation or give reference or something like that ?

Comment: Interesting expression !

Comment: Just use $\int_0^{\infty} e^{-sa} ds=\frac{1}{a}$ applied to $a=X_1+\cdots+X_n.$

Comment: got it. Thanks ! Nice ! But do you really need the factor $n$ in your expression ?

Comment: Yes, I do. $nE(\frac{X_1Y_1}{X_1+\cdots+X_n})=E(\frac{X_1Y_1+\cdots+X_nY_n}{X_1+\cdots+x_n}).$

Comment: Thanks got it !